# Apple ID locked - reset password

Tags: apple-id, password, recovery

So my son forgot the password of email and Apple ID password.
When we go to reset, after we enter the Apple ID, it says it will send instructions by email to ****@icloud.com
He can't get in his email and it's the only option we have.
Is there any way of doing this still or is he basically out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [contact Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204169) about this, as they have tools to help recover Apple IDs like security questions, backup emails, and simply verifying your biographic information against your Apple ID.